# Displaying SMS message once received in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I am trying to write a simple android program that listens to SMS messages, and once a message is received, it displays it in a toast.

Below is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zaidalmahmoud.expenseless">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is my SMS Listener:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String msgBody;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

            Toast.makeText(context,"message received:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(context,"message is:"+msgBody,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and below is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    SmsListener smsListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        smsListener= new SmsListener();
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(smsListener, intentFilter);


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Unregister the SMS receiver
        unregisterReceiver(smsListener);
    }


}
```

Surprisingly, I am getting no output at all (no Toast message) once the SMS is received. Can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: you know you need to request runtime permission if you are on android 6+ ?

Comment: No, is that other than the 3 permissions that I already included?

Comment: please follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score -1):

You are not declaring your receiver in Manifest file, because of it will not listen anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.zaidalmahmoud.expenseless">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <receiver android:name=".SmsListener"/>

</application>
```

Comment: As I expected, your solution doesn't work. In fact, I am already declaring my receiver in the activity, so there is no point of declaring it again in the manifest file.